# How to replace the dots in abbreviations using regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

Basically, I want to drop all the dots in the abbreviations like "L.L.C.", converting to "LLC". I don't have a list of all the abbreviations. I want to convert them as they are found. This step is performed before sentence tokenization.

```
text = """
    Proligo L.L.C. is a limited liability company.  
    S.A. is a place.  
    She works for AAA L.P. in somewhere.  
    """
text = re.sub(r"(?:([A-Z])\.){2,}", "\1", text)
```

This does not work.

I want to remove the dots from the abbreviations so that the dots will not break the sentence tokenizer.

Thank you!

P.S. Sorry for not being clear enough.  I edited the sample text.

Comment: A real-time regexp tester is key to figuring out problems like this.  Google for one specific to the Rex Exp domain you are using.  (i.e. Perl, Python, C#, etc)  For instance, a quick Google found this one: https://pythex.org/.  There might be a better one, but it is a place to start.

Comment: Your requirements are still a bit unclear. Should `"A."` be subbed to `"A"`? How about `"b.b.c."`? How about `"A.F"`? Please make a list of all of the patterns you want to match, otherwise, answers will be highly presumptuous, like `re.sub('\.', '')`, which just kills all periods in your document.

Comment: For now, I'm looking for ([a-zA-Z])\.){2,}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a callback function with `re.sub`:

```
def callback( str ):
    return str.replace('.', '')

text = "L.L.C., S.A., L.P."
text = re.sub(r"(?:[A-Z]\.)+", lambda m: callback(m.group()), text)
print(text)
```

The regex pattern `(?:[A-Z]\.)+` will match any number of capital abbreviations.  Then, for each match, the callback function will strip off dots.

Answer (score -1):

```py
import re
string = 'ha.f.d.s.a.s.d.f'
re.sub('\.', '', string)

#output
hafdsasdf
```

Note that this only works properly if your text does not contain multiple sentences. If it does it will create one long sentence as all '.' are replaced.

Answer (score -1):

Use this regular expression:

```
>>> re.sub(r"(?<=[A-Z]).", "", text)
'LLC, SA, LP'
>>>
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kxS4gI/1/)

Answer (score -1):

The answers here are extremely aggressive: any capital alphabetical character followed by a period will be replaced.

I'd recommend:

```
text = "L.L.C., S.A., L.P."
text = re.sub(r"L\.L\.C\.|S\.A\.|L\.P\.", lambda x: x.group().replace(".", ""), text)
print(text) # => "LLC, SA, LP"
```

This will only match the abbreviations you're asking for. You can add word boundaries for additional strictness.

Comment: The other answers are very aggressive, but this is very specific.

Comment: @KevinRamirezZavalza That's exactly the point of the answer, avoiding false positives.

Comment: Yes but he mentions that he does not have the list of all abbreviations, so the regex is not fixed only to the examples he gave.

Comment: Right, and I'm suggesting that just blasting a potentially giant corpus and replacing _any_ occurrence of a capital followed by a period is very dangerous. It's much better to enumerate the most common abbreviations explicitly. If you can't do them all, then I'd suggest at least matching `[A-Z]\.[A-Z]\.[A-Z]\.`. Something like `(?<=[A-Z]).` as suggested by all existing answers is going to blast way too much in any remotely realistic use case. It'll turn "He's better at chess than I. This is interesting." into "He's better at chess than I This is interesting." and all sorts of false positives.

Comment: I [left a comment asking OP to clarify their use case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56590429/how-to-replace-the-dots-in-abbreviations-using-regex-in-python/56590495?noredirect=1#comment99758462_56590429) back in 2019, and my feeling hasn't changed since then. Feel free to downvote me, but it's the only answer that is at least explicit about the risks.

Comment: "I want to remove the dots from the abbreviations so that the dots will not break the sentence tokenizer." Regex isn't appropriate for this task--OP will likely need NLP to determine the difference between a sentence and a non-sentence abbreviation. There are too many edge cases.